# OmniSharp-Roslyn scanning/discovery process not working

Tags: monaco-editor, omnisharp

I started to play around with Omnisharp-Roslyn and I was able to make it work with Monaco!

I dont know why but if I make changes to my file Omnisharp doesn't seem to Read / Discover new items...

I tried to configure the [file options](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options#file-options) without success.

I'm out of solutions... What Am I missing here?

I'm using the version [`3.5.0-beta.1879`](https://roslynomnisharp.blob.core.windows.net/releases/3.5.0-beta.1879/omnisharp-win-x86.zip) over **stdio**

Comment: Hello, please can you provide some example how to connect Monaco and Omnisharp? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some one came across the same issue.

I manage to make it work using the [/filesChanged](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp.Abstractions/Models/v1/FilesChanged/FilesChangedRequest.cs) command using the [ChangeType](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp.Abstractions/FileWatching/FileChangeType.cs) `Unspecified`